# Any other cases similar to $\sqrt[4]{\frac {3+2\sqrt[4]{5}}{3-2\sqrt[4]{5}}}=\frac 12 (3+\sqrt[4]{5}+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[4]{125})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

Ramanujan gave many curious identities, one of which was $$\sqrt[4]{\frac {3+2\sqrt[4]{5}}{3-2\sqrt[4]{5}}}=\frac {\sqrt[4]{5}+1}{\sqrt[4]{5}-1}=\frac 12(3+\sqrt[4]5+\sqrt5+\sqrt[4]{125})\tag1$$
And another one:$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[5]{\frac {32}5}-\sqrt[5]{\frac {27}5}}=\sqrt[5]{\frac 1{25}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac {3}{25}}-\sqrt[5]{\frac {9}{25}}\tag2$$

---

> **Question:** Is there some algebraic method to *prove* $(1)$ and $(2)$, and can that method be generalized? And more specifically, can both $(1)$ and $(2)$ be represented as a sum of radicals of the same degree? Such as $\sqrt[4]{A+B\sqrt[4]{C}}=\sqrt[4]{X}+\sqrt[4]{Y}+\sqrt[4]{Z}$.

---

Also, I do realize that for $(1)$, you can raise everything to the fourth power and simplify to get an identity (such as $1=1$), but it doesn't provide insight on *why* or *how* the equation holds.

Comment: There are similar others. To name a few: $$\sqrt[3]{\cfrac{\sqrt[4]{27}+4-\sqrt 3}{\sqrt[4]{27}-4+\sqrt 3}}=\cfrac{\sqrt[4]3+1}{\sqrt[4]3-1}.$$ $$\sqrt{\cfrac{\sqrt 3+\sqrt{5-3\sqrt[3]5+\sqrt[3]{25}}}{\sqrt 3-\sqrt{5-3\sqrt[3]5+\sqrt[3]{25}}}}=\cfrac{\sqrt[6]5+1}{\sqrt[6]5-1}.$$ $$\begin{align}\sqrt{\cfrac{7-\sqrt 5 + \sqrt{6\big(5-\sqrt 5\big)}}{9-\sqrt 5 + \sqrt{6\big(5+\sqrt 5\big)}}}&=\cfrac 12\sqrt{7+\sqrt 5-\sqrt{6\big(5+\sqrt 5\big)}} \\ &=\cfrac 14\left\{\sqrt 3 \big(\sqrt 5 + 1\big) - \big(\sqrt 5 - 1\big)\sqrt{\cfrac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}}\right\}\\ &= 2\sin \cfrac{2\pi}{15}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Regarding that last one, we also have: $$\sqrt{\cfrac{7-\sqrt 5 + \sqrt{6\big(5-\sqrt 5\big)}}{7+\sqrt 5 - \sqrt{6\big(5+\sqrt 5\big)}}}=\cfrac{1+\sqrt 5}2+\sqrt{\cfrac{3\big(5-\sqrt 5\big)}2}$$

Answer (score 3):

The first identity of (1) can not be generalized, namely $5$ is the only integer satisfying (1). To see this, let
$$ \sqrt[4]{\frac{a+b\sqrt[4]{p}}{a-b\sqrt[4]{p}}}=\frac{\sqrt[4]{p}+q}{\sqrt[4]{p}-q} \tag{3}$$
where $p,q$ are integers such that $\sqrt[4]{p},\sqrt{p}$ are not integers and $a,b,$ are rationals. Then (3) is equivalent to
$$ (a+b\sqrt[4]{p})(\sqrt[4]{p}-q)^4-(a-b\sqrt[4]{p})(\sqrt[4]{p}+q)^4=0 $$
or
$$ \sqrt[4]{p}\bigg\{2q(-2a+3qb)\sqrt{p}+\big[-4q^3a+(p+q^4)b\big]\bigg\}=0. $$
Let
$$ \bigg\{\begin{array}{ll}
-2a+3qb&=&0,\\
-4q^3a+(p+q^4)b&=&0,
\end{array}$$
which is a system of linear homogeneous equations. It has nonzero solutions iff
$$ \det\bigg(\begin{matrix}
-2&3q\\
-4q^3&p+q^4
\end{matrix}\bigg)=0 $$
from which one obtains $p=5q^4$ and $a=\frac32qb$. Thus (3) becomes
$$ \sqrt[4]{\frac{3+2\sqrt[4]{5}}{3-2\sqrt[4]{5}}}=\frac{\sqrt[4]{5}+1}{\sqrt[4]{5}-1}. $$

Comment: Aw, that's unfortunate. Can the same process be used to prove $(2)$? More specifically, $$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[5]{\frac pa}-\sqrt[5]{\frac qa}}=\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}+\sqrt[3]{z}$$

Comment: Is it also possible to extend this to other degrees? Such as$$\sqrt[3]{\frac {a+b\sqrt[3]{p}}{a-b\sqrt[3]{p}}}$$

Comment: @Frank, you can try.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't work.